# Why did Holden tear up the essay about Allie's baseball glove?

Tags: j-d-salinger, the-catcher-in-the-rye

Towards the beginning of J. D. Salinger's *The Catcher in the Rye*, when Stradlater asks Holden to write his paper for him, Holden writes it about his brother Allie's baseball glove, which evidently holds a significant level of importance to Holden. However, Stradlater doesn't apprefciate it so much, claiming it had to be about a room or something:

> "You said it had to be descriptive. What the hell's the difference if it's about a baseball glove?"
> "God damn it." He was sore as hell. He was really furious. "You always do everything backwards." He looked at me. "No wonder you're flunking the hell out of here," he said. "You don't do *one damn thing* the way you're supposed to. I mean it. Not one damn thing."
> "All right, give it back to me, then," I said. I went over and pulled it right out of his goddam hand. Then I tore it up.
> "What the hellja do *that* for?" he said.
> I didn't even answer him. I ust threw the pieces in the wastebasket. Then I lay down on my bed, and we both didn't say anything for a long time.
> <sub>*The Catcher in the Rye*, chapter 6</sub>

Why does Holden tear up the essay in this scene? What's going on with him? He refuses to answer Stradlater about why he tears it up, and the subject changes soon to the topic of Jane.

What's going through Holden's mind during this scene, and why was it necessary to tear up the essay?